# I am developing snake game, I write few code line , but speed of snake is to fast, I want to slow down the speed to normal, How to do that? In python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-chrome, pycharm

In python

```
import time
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# screen height and width
height = 600
width = 600

# snake initial positinn
x_coordinate = 0
y_coordinate = 0

game_on = True
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(height=height, width=width)
screen.title("Snake Game")
full_snake = []
screen.tracer(0)

# create a snake 3X3
for _ in range(3):
    snake = Turtle("square")
    snake.color("white")
    snake.penup()
    snake.goto(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
    x_coordinate -= 20
    full_snake.append(snake)
snake_head = full_snake[0]



# function to operate the snake
def up():
    if snake_head.heading() != 270:
        snake_head.setheading(90)


def down():
    if snake_head.heading() != 90:
        snake_head.setheading(270)

def right():
    if snake_head.heading() != 180:
        snake_head.setheading(0)

def left():
    if snake_head.heading() != 0:
        snake_head.setheading(180)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(up, "w")
screen.onkey(down, "s")
screen.onkey(right, "d")
screen.onkey(left, "a")


# function for snakes part to attached
def attached():
    for i in range(len(full_snake) - 1, 0, -1):
        new_x = full_snake[i - 1].xcor()
        new_y = full_snake[i - 1].ycor()
        full_snake[i].goto(new_x, new_y)
    snake_head.fd(20)

# to move the snake
while game_on:
    snake_head.speed(1)
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    for snake in full_snake:
        attached()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**in this code snake speed is fast, I want to slow down to normal where I can placed speed() method or any method
Turtle module from python
expected output : speed of snake to be normal without detaching other two blocks**
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: did you try increasing your `time.sleep(0.1)` ? maybe `time.sleep(0.5)`?

Comment: Increasing time.sleep() causes delayed in operation, like you press "w" for snake movment to up , but you increase the time it respond get delayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`ontimer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) method instead to control the snake movement. I modified your code a bit. You can check if the snake hits the wall too and set game_on to false in the `move_snake` function.

```
import time
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# screen height and width
height = 600
width = 600

# snake initial position
x_coordinate = 0
y_coordinate = 0

game_on = True
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(height=height, width=width)
screen.title("Snake Game")
full_snake = []
screen.tracer(0)

# create a snake 3X3
for _ in range(3):
    snake = Turtle("square")
    snake.color("white")
    snake.penup()
    snake.goto(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
    x_coordinate -= 20
    full_snake.append(snake)
snake_head = full_snake[0]

# function to operate the snake
def up():
    if snake_head.heading() != 270:
        snake_head.setheading(90)

def down():
    if snake_head.heading() != 90:
        snake_head.setheading(270)

def right():
    if snake_head.heading() != 180:
        snake_head.setheading(0)

def left():
    if snake_head.heading() != 0:
        snake_head.setheading(180)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(up, "w")
screen.onkey(down, "s")
screen.onkey(right, "d")
screen.onkey(left, "a")

# function for snake parts to attached
def attached():
    for i in range(len(full_snake) - 1, 0, -1):
        new_x = full_snake[i - 1].xcor()
        new_y = full_snake[i - 1].ycor()
        full_snake[i].goto(new_x, new_y)
    snake_head.fd(20)

# New function to move the snake
def move_snake():
    attached()
    screen.update()
    # updated the height and width variables to fit the actual screen size (useful when screen is resized)
    height = screen.window_height()
    width = screen.window_width()
    # check if the snake head hits the wall (19 or 20 pixels away looks fine but can be ajusted) then set game_on to false and stop the function execution
    if snake_head.xcor() >= width/2 - 20 or snake_head.xcor() <= -width/2 + 19 or snake_head.ycor() >= height/2 - 19 or snake_head.ycor() <= -height/2 + 20:
        game_on = False
        return
    # timer to recursively call the move_snake function every 500 milliseconds
    screen.ontimer(move_snake, 500)  # adapt to your desired speed (the lower the faster)

# start moving the snake
move_snake()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: it works but, if snake touches the wall then loop should be over but we cant end this loop.

Comment: you could check if the snake hits the wall in the move_snake function and stop the game loop when that happens. I will update my answer to take that into account